# Display [...] to let user know more characters are available off screen

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

When a textbox has overflow due to too many characters how can I display a `[...]` inside the textbox to let them know more characters are off screen?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/p75TH/474/)

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
      return {
        example: "asdfasdfasdfasdf qwer asdf zxcv 123"
      };
    },

    handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({example: e.currentTarget.value});
    },

    render: function() {
      return ( 
        <form role="form">
          <div>
            <label>Field 1</label> 
            <input
              placeholder = "Field"
              value = {this.state.example}
              onChange = {this.handleChange}
            /> 
          </div> 
        </form>
      );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<App />,document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One css trick is using `text-overflow: ellipsis`. It requires a few more rules though so here they are:

```
input {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And of course play with the width of the parent container if it's not working well enough as it needs to be able to "overflow", otherwise it'll never be hidden.